# data not inserted in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my flask model(I am using Flask-Sqlalchemy).

```
class Feeds(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feed_link = db.Column(db.String(100))
    url = db.Column(db.String(100))
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    summary = db.Column(db.Text)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    published_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, feed_link, url, title, summary, content, published_date):
        self.feed_link = feed_link
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.summary = summary
        self.content = content
        self.published_date = published_date
        print self.published_date 
        #self.created_at = datetime.utcnow()        
        self.created_at = date.today()
```

And this is where I insert the data.

```
for i in range(0,len(feed['entries'])):
        post = {}
        post['title'] = feed['entries'][i].title,
        post['summary'] = feed['entries'][i].summary,
        post['url'] = feed['entries'][i].link
        post['content'] = ''
        for content in feed['entries'][i]['content']:
            post['content'] = post['content'] + content.value
        post['published_date'] = feed['entries'][i].published_parsed
        db.session.add(Feeds(feed_link=rss_link, url=post['url'], title=post['title'][0], summary=post['summary'][0], 
                content=post['content'], published_date=post['published_date']))
        db.session.commit()
```

All fields are inserted properly except self.published_date. While inserting, the data exists but while retrieving the date field is 0. Here I am using mysql as the database.

Can somebody tell me, what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that

```
feed['entries'][i].published_parsed
```

is a date but as a string. While creating a Feed and passing post['published_date'] it should be a datetime object so you should pass strptime(post['published_date'], "your_format").

Comment: In print self.published_date , this is printing the date (as a date object). But when I try to store, I can't store it.

Comment: Are you sure ? Please check with print type(post['published_date'])

Comment: Can you please provide some kind of log : eg. 1. print  post['published_date'], 2. print type(post['published_date']) . 3. Maybe pull create Feed to a variable and print later Feed.published_date